# iOS Local notification sound keeps playing when app is opened

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

I have a local notification scheduled with a 30 second long audio file. When the notification fires, if I launch the app from the notification banner or notification centre, the app will open normally and the notification sound will stop playing. However, when the notification fires and if I launch the app by clicking on the app icon, the notification sound will keep playing. How can I get it to stop playing upon launch?

Comment: have you tried calling cancelLocalNotification:

Comment: The local notification is set to repeat every minute and I don't want to cancel it because it should keep ringing if the user leaves the app before doing a certain task. (It's an alarm clock that won't stop ringing until you do specific tasks)

Comment: You can cancel and re-schedule though...

Comment: True, but is there no straightforward way?

Comment: I don't think there is a more straightforward or complex option...